# Add attachment to gmail app via intent in Android

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, gmail

I have tried adding an attachment (csv file) to the mail intent. When the i start the intent and choose Gmail as the app, it says "Permission denied for the attachment". How do i solve this?

This is the code that i'm using

```
try {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("address", input.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
    String gmail=sharedPreferences.getString("address","");
    Uri dat = Uri.fromFile(path);

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sendIntent.setType("text/html");
       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, gmail);
       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Stuff");
       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, dat);
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email..."));

}catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Whath is  the 'path' to the file?

Comment: File path=new File(file.getAbsolutePath())

Comment: No, where exactly does this file reside? How are you defining `path`?

Comment: You told me noting. Then what is the value of file.getAbsolutePath() ?

Comment: If you try to attach a csv file then why do you use text/html ?

Comment: /data/data/com.example.user.glukozko/files/meritve.csv @greenapps

Comment: Then your csv file is in private internal storage of your app. No other apps have access. Only your app. So the used email app has no access too. Put the file on another place. Or use a FileProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Your csv file is in private internal storage of your app. No other apps have access. Only your app. So the used email app has no access too. Put the file on another place. Or use a FileProvider.

Comment: And how do I use FileProvider? I have read the documentation on the Android Developers site but I still don't quite understand it. @greenappps

Comment: That question is asked at least two times every week. So google or just read some pages here.